# Permission denied (publickey). Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer

Tags: amazon-ec2

hi im configuring ftp on amazon Ec2 micro linux instance but i found error

**Permission denied (publickey). Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer**

i have install vsftpd on my instance,configure fire wall open port 21, 2020 edit vsftpd.conf 
enabled anonymous login = false

add user to my instance,when i login with my user above error occur,

help me what im doing wrong and where is the problem, why this error occurs.thank in advance.

Comment: Since when is FTP using asymmetric key encryption? You are mixing FTP and SFTP. SFTP is using port 22.

Comment: And why is this old post popping up on the frontpage. Nothing new here...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, if I remember rightly I solved it by changing from passive to active mode.

Comment: You can change the connection mode in your FTP client, probably under connection settings or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the folder you're connecting to is owned by root and no other user/group has write priveleges:

```
sudo chown root:root /home/ftpuser/
sudo chmod 755 /home/ftpuser/
```

You can debug connection errors by using

```
sftp -vvv ftpuser@12.34.56.78
```